# Approximating stochastic integral with Weiner process (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, integral

Is there a toolbox or available MATLAB function that will allow me to solve the following approximation of stochastic integrals, where z is a Wiener process:

[image]

Comment: SO is not there as a human-based search engine. You need to show that you put effort into achieving something, encountered an obstacle, and now need practical help. See the about page: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." – Seeing that equation, I don't see why you need a toolbox, Matlab provides all the tools to implement that.

Comment: In addition to @ADonda's advice, consider posting your (refined) question in stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```
    %Lets say n is 100 and dt is 1/252 and k = .1
    n = 100;
    dt = 1/252;
    k = 0.1;
    dz = randn(n,1); %get random increments: normal
    %dz = 2*(randi(2,n,1)-1.5); % or plus/minus ones : bernoulli
    fnt = exp(-k*(n*dt - [0:n-1]*dt))*sqrt(dt)*dz;
```

Comment: According to the question, `z` is supposed to be a Wiener process so its increments, `dz` should have standard deviation of `sqrt(dt)`.